Automate adding a blank page to PDF files
I have a long list of PDF files that I combine in Adobe Acrobat, and I need to add a blank page at the end of each file. Each file can have one or multiple pages. I do this task regularly, so it would be extremely helpful to automate. Right now I use Adobe's "Organize Pages" tool to manually add the blank pages and it's very tedious.
Any ideas on how to automate adding the blank pages? Ideally a Javascript code I can run in Adobe? I already run a script in Adobe when the files are open. Or maybe something with Windows Powershell that applies the action to an entire folder?
Thank you!!!

I was able to find an answer with Adobe Acrobat, which is what I originally asked for. (I'm not able to download other programs on my work computer, and I certainly don't want a solution that requires payment.)
The solution involves using Adobe Acrobat's "Action Wizard" since adding a blank page is a preset action already. The Action Wizard allows you to select a folder or multiple files to apply the action to - no coding needed. Here are some instructions that I copied: https://evermap.com/ActionWizardDC.asp
